# Javascript for menus enter key and navigation through up and down key

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="dropmenu" title="Masters" >Masters</a>|</li>


<div id="dropmenu" class="dropmenudiv_a">

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:imageClick('countryList.htm');">Geographic Masters</a> 

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:imageClick('zoneList.htm');">Sales Masters</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:imageClick('documentType.htm');">KYC Masters</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Really unclear what you're asking us.

Comment: Can you add any description? or what do you want??

Comment: are you trying to navigate in your menu using arrow keys

Comment: If you want people to spend their time on helping you, the least you could do is spend a little time in explaining yourself more clearly. A title and a chunk of code aren't enough.

Comment: when I press enter key sub menu should popup and I should be able to navigate submenu through up and down key.!!

Comment: @anni yes i want no navigate using arrow keys

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [here](http://jqueryui.com/menu/). I hope it might help you. And next time when you ask please try to make it clear.

Comment: Hi Krishna my problem is when I press enter key on menu submenu should pop up and i should be able to navigate submenu using up and down arrow ket

Comment: @user3655212 use the link and navigate to widget with tab then you will be able to do navigation on submenu also :)